# Adding in Maps to Silverlight Project

Tags: silverlight, dictionary, geolocation, bing-maps, openstreetmap

Im wanting to know if there is any commercial free map display options for Silverlight projects these days? I tried to run DeepEarth and it just wouldnt play for me in SL5.

Im keen to run OpenStreetMaps so we can deploy it commercially without licensing issues.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use bing maps ,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc980922.aspx

http://www.microsoft.com/maps/isdk/silverlight/

```
<UserControl x:Class="MapControlInteractiveSdk.Tutorials.TutorialDefaultMap"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:m="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Maps.MapControl;assembly=Microsoft.Maps.MapControl">
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <m:Map CredentialsProvider="{StaticResource MyCredentials}" />
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Bing has two type licence,if you use it as commercial you should pay for it.

GeoService is very successful. You just separate address fields by comma service returns you latitude and attitude etc.

You can also change your provider for google.  Telerik also has successful Api for it.
You can use Telerik's Open Street Map provider its free as far as I know. Sure if you got telerik components. 
http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#Map/GeoImageryProviders

In my opinion:

Without paying a mount of money developing silverlight applications is not be efficient. I can't think a silverlight without Telerik now. Sometimes paying a month of money bring us less cost.

Comment: I would be curious to see who let you consume their tiles with no fee at all (even Open Street Map tiles hosted on web servers represents bandwith cost..)

Comment: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tile_usage_policy#Alternative_OpenStreetMap_Tile_Providers

Comment: Yes, I knew those providers, but as you might see (CloudMade for example) are not all free and most of them are limited in the number of tiles you can load.

Comment: In Turkish there is an idiom "How much money how much meatball"

Comment: Yes I agree and that's my point. In my opinion, the user here, even if you recommend to use Telerik, needs to keep in mind that it's not always 'free' since the tile hosted on servers might cost money, especialy if the application used lots of map operation (zooming/panning etc..)